# Can't send InputStream object using grails rest-client-builder

Tags: rest, grails, grails-plugin

I've been using rest-client-builder plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder) and faced with problem to send a file as inputStream object.

From plugin documentation:

> > > Multipart requests are possible by setting properties of the request body to File, URL, byte[] or InputStream instances:

```
def resp = rest.post(url) {
        contentType "multipart/form-data"
        zip = new File(pluginPackage)
        pom = new File(pomFile)
        xml = new File(pluginXmlFile)
    }
```

My code:

```
def post(String url, InputStream photo, String contentType, Cookie[] cookies = null) {
    def rest = new RestBuilder()

    def cookiesHeaderString = ""
    if (cookies) {
        cookiesHeaderString = WebUtils.buildCookiesHeader(cookies)
    }

    def resp = rest.post(url) {
        header "Cookie", cookiesHeaderString
        file = photo
        contentType "multipart/form-data"
    }

    return resp?.responseEntity?.body
}
```

Could somebody suggest how can I send an InputStream object or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What goes wrong with your code?

Comment: something goes wrong with contentType: Message: null
    Line | Method
->>  307 | getContentType          in javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap

Answer (score 1):

For File type we need to set "file" property on the RequestCustomizer.  The below code worked for me.

```
File myFile = new File("myFile.txt")

def restResponse = rest.post(url) {
   header headerName, headerValue
   contentType "multipart/form-data" 
   setProperty "file", myFile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am quite late for this answer but I was searching for the answer and nothing seemed to work. So, by trial and error I finally have found my answer working, so would like to post it here.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate()
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new  HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

 def restBuilder=new RestBuilder(restTemplate)  
File f = new File("C:/Users/USER/Documents/hello.txt")
 MultiValueMap<String, File> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, File>()
 form.add("fileUpload", f)
         return client.post(path) {
               auth('ngtest1', 'ngtest1')
               header :['contentType':"multipart/form-data"]
               setProperty "fileUpload", f
               body (form)
         }
```

This worked for me. I have given the name as 'fileUpload' in my application. Hope this helps.